# What is the easiest way to get a list of whole factor pairs of a given integer?

Tags: python, math

What is the easiest way to get a list of whole factor pairs of a given integer?

For example: `f(20)` would return `[(1,20), (2,10), (4,5)]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to get all the divisors of a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171765/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-the-divisors-of-a-number)

Comment: partial overlap, but different question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def f(value):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, int(value**0.5)+1):
        if value % i == 0:
            factors.append((i, value / i))
    return factors
```

Or the same thing using a list comprehension:

```
def f(val):
    return [(i, val / i) for i in range(1, int(val**0.5)+1) if val % i == 0]
```

Comment: I added the hardcoded factor of 1 to micro optimise the function (as there's little point doing % 1) - but what do people think about this?  Does the messiness of the code and the inability to accept values of less than 1 outweigh the exceptionally minor optimisation?

Comment: It's a bit problematic as it returns 1 as a factor of 0, which is "incorrect". That could be fixed by doing `result = [(1, value)] * (value > 0)` which is possibly still faster than doing an extra iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Or this:

```
def f(n):
        factors_list = []
        for i in xrange(1, int(n**0.5) + 1):
            if n % i == 0:
                factors_list.append((i, n/i))
        return factors_list

print f(20)
```

EDIT: Or in a one-liner using list comprehension:

```
def f(n):
    return [(i, n / i) for i in xrange(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0]

print f(36)
```

EDIT2: If you want the function to work for negative integers (as well as 0 and positive integers) use:

```
def f(n):
    return [(i, n / i) for i in xrange(1, int(math.sqrt(math.fabs(n))) + 1) if n % i == 0]

print f(-36)
```

Comment: @odonnell: `xrange` to speed things up when using large numbers (no need in Python 3, however), `ceil` for clarity and brevity.

Comment: Wouldn't `ceil` remove an integer square root from the factor_list? You would need to add 1 to it.

Comment: @Brendan: do you have an example?

Comment: I like your one-liner, it is nice not to need to explicitly create an empty list.

Comment: @Benjamin: If n = 16, the range would give us 1->4, since 'math.ceil(16**0.6) = 4'. Since xrange and range are exclude the end value from the iteration, we would be unable to have (4,4) in factors_list.

Comment: @Brendan: very true. I will change back to int(n**0.5) + 1

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def f(n):
    from itertools import takewhile
    if not isinstance(n,int):
          raise ValueError("supplied %s type, requires integer input" %(type(n).__name__))
    return [(i,n/i) for i in takewhile(lambda x:x*x<n,xrange(1,n)) if (n%i)==0]
```

Comment: There's so much wrong to unfortunate with the second line... (1) `assert` is for sanity checks, not for input validation. (2) Explicit typechecking is usually a bad idea anyway. (3) But if you do it, at least use `isinstance` (which considers inheritance). (4) Also, if you absolutely have to check if the type is exactly `T`, better use `type(...) is T` - `is` is more appropriate for singletons (a type is essentially one) and `==` *could* have a broken overload.

Comment: Any reason why you do (n/i)*i==n, rather than use mod (%)?

Comment: @Benjamin: Not with integer division, which truncates. Although in Python 3 you're right because they changed `/` to always return a float.

Comment: @Benjamin: try typing `(5/2)*2 == 5` in your python console if you are using Python 2.x

Comment: Not to criticize excessively, but something along the lines of `raise ValueError("Can only factor integer, not '{}'".format(type(n).__name__))` would be *really* good imho. Perhaps I've spent too much time with the FP guys, but a number crunching function shouldn't output anything imho.

Comment: Checking types is silly, but if you must do it don't just print a message and try to muddle through. Raise a TypeError. But seriously, don't check the parameter types.

Comment: I think your list comprehension is backwards. I also think it's cooler to acknowledge when you see a good answer than to edit it into your own.

Comment: @Benjamin, didn't mean to do that, I was trying to use list comprehension, and thought I needed ceil to do that. The new edit doesn't use that.

Comment: @highBandWidth: I meant that your answer is now completely different from your original answer.

Comment: The while loop version was better, it was possible to understand.