# Divisors of a number: How can I improve this code to find the number of divisors of big numbers?

Tags: python, math

My code is very slow when it comes to very large numbers.

```
def divisors(num):
    divs = 1
    if num == 1:
        return 1

    for i in range(1, int(num/2)):
        if num % i == 0:
            divs += 1
        elif int(num/2) == i:
            break
        else:
            pass
    return divs
```

For 10^9 i get a run time of 381.63s.

Comment: Trying to break RSA? ;)

Comment: @CongMa Not yet ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that determines the multiplicities of the various distinct prime factors of `n`. Each such power, `k`, contributes a factor of `k+1` to the total number of divisors.

```
import math

def smallest_divisor(p,n):
    #returns the smallest divisor of n which is greater than p
    for d in range(p+1,1+math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
        if n % d == 0:
            return d
    return n

def divisors(n):
    divs = 1
    p = 1
    while p < n:
        p = smallest_divisor(p,n)
        k = 0
        while n % p == 0:
            k += 1
            n //= p
        divs *= (k+1)
    return divs - 1
```

It returns the number of proper divisors (so not counting the number itself). If you want to count the number itself, don't subtract 1 from the result.

It works rapidly with numbers of the size 10**9, though will slow down dramatically with even larger numbers.

Comment: there is no need to keep the powers in a list

Comment: @Copperfield You are right, of course. I did that originally because I wanted to inspect them to make sure that I had the logic right. I'll tweak the code to keep a running product instead. Thanks.

Comment: @Copperfield Great job, I finally arrived at a faster solution with my code running time goes down to about 0.008s for 10^9. As you can see from my code bellow it spends allot of time actually finding the divisors. Can your code also be adapted to get the divisors? I'm working on that but if you can help ***

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
import math

def num_of_divisors(n):
    ct = 1
    rest = n
    for i in range(2, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)))+1):
        while rest%i==0:
            ct += 1
            rest /= i
            print i  # the factors
        if rest == 1:
            break
    if rest != 1:
       print rest   # the last factor
       ct += 1
    return ct

def main():
    number = 2**31 * 3**13
    print '{} divisors in {}'.format(num_of_divisors(number), number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

We can stop searching for factors at the square root of `n`. Multiple factors are found in the `while` loop. And when a factor is found we divide it out from the number.
**edit:**
@Mark Ransom is right, the factor count was 1 too small for numbers where one factor was greater than the square root of the number, for instance `3*47*149*6991`. The last check for `rest != 1` accounts for that. 
The number of factors is indeed correct then - you don't have to check beyond `sqrt(n)` for this.
Both statements where a number is printed can be used to append this number to the number of factors, if desired.

Comment: If you stop searching at the square root you will only count half of the factors. If you try to account for that you'll be very susceptible to off-by-one errors.

Comment: You are right, if the last remainder is greater than one it's a factor as well (1 is assumed implicitely at the beginning with `ct = 1`). I've corrected my code for this, thanks. For your other remark regarding `sqrt(n)`, can you give me an example of a number where the script returns a wrong count?

Comment: Try `num_of_divisors(5)`, `num_of_divisors(25)`, and `num_of_divisors(125)`.

Comment: You're right, a one-off error in the `range()` as the upper limit is not included. Code would fail on a square number. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Division is expensive, multiplication is cheap.

Factorize the number into primes. (Download the list of primes, keep dividing from the `<= sqrt(num)`.)

Then count all the permutations.

If your number is a power of exactly one prime, `p^n`, you obvioulsy have `n` divisors for it, excluding 1; 8 = 2^3 has 3 divisors: 8, 4, 2.

In general case, your number factors into k primes: `p0^n0 * p1^n1 * ... * pk^nk`. It has `(n0 + 1) * (n1 + 1) * .. * (nk + 1)` divisors. The "+1" term counts for the case when *all other* powers are 0, that is, contribute a 1 to the multiplication.

Alternatively, you could just google and [RTFM](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/tau.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of my code in the question. The running time is better, 0.008s for 10^9 now.

```
def divisors(num):
    ceiling = int(sqrt(num))
    divs = []
    if num == 1:
        return [1]
    for i in range(1, ceiling + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            divs.append(num / i)
            if i != num // i:
                divs.append(i)
    return divs
```

> It is important for me to also keep the divisors, so if this can still
>   be improved I'd be glad.

Comment: if you want to find the divisors rather than the number of them, you can follow the method in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/171765/5644961), in either case the best way is to factor the number

Comment: @Copperfield Thanks but I already went there and the best code I got from there has the same running time as mine but for the code from Tomas Kulich which gives me this <<generator object divisors at 0x00000000031886C0>> on running and my reputations do not permit me to comment directly on his answer in order to figure out the problem.

Comment: generator don't do anything unless you ask for its values by iterating over them or calling list (or similar) on them