# String subpattern recognition optimization

Tags: python-3.x, performance

In this kata you need to build a function to return either true/True or false/False if a string can be seen as the repetition of a simpler/shorter subpattern or not.

```
For example:

has_subpattern("a") == False #no repeated pattern
has_subpattern("aaaa") == True #created repeating "a"
has_subpattern("abcd") == False #no repeated pattern
has_subpattern("abababab") == True #created repeating "ab"
has_subpattern("ababababa") == False #cannot be entirely reproduced repeating a pattern
```

Strings will never be empty and can be composed of any character (just consider upper- and lowercase letters as different entities) and can be pretty long (keep an eye on performances!).

My solution is:

```
def has_subpattern(string):
    string_size = len(string)

    for i in range(1, string_size):
        slice1 = string[:i]
        appearence_count = string.count(slice1)
        slice1_len = len(slice1)
        if appearence_count > 0:
            if appearence_count * slice1_len == string_size:
                return True

    return False
```

Obviously there are weak and too slow things like `slice1 = string[:i]` and `string.count()` in loop..
Is there better ways to solve an issue or ways to improve performance ?

Comment: What makes you think that `.count()` is slow?

Comment: @norok2 that `.count()` is loop over `string` variable each time in `for` loop, if string is 30k chars it's tooo expensive to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within standard Python, the bottlenecks here will be `count`, which enjoys C speed implementation and the looping.
The looping itself may be hard to speed-up (althogh Cython may be of some help).

Hence, the most important optimization is to reduce the number of loopings.

One obvious way is to let `range()` do not exceed half the size of the input (`+ 2`: `+ 1` for rounding issues, `+ 1` for end extrema exclusion in `range()`):

Also, `string` is a standard Python module, so better not use it as a variable name.

```
def has_subpattern_loop(text):
    for i in range(1, len(text) // 2 + 2):
        subtext = text[:i]
        num_subtext = text.count(subtext)
        if num_subtext > 1 and num_subtext * len(subtext) == len(text):
            return True
    return False
```

A much more effective way of restricting the number of calls to `count` is to skip computation when `i` is not a multiple of the length of the input.

```
def has_subpattern_loop2(text):
    for i in range(1, len(text) // 2 + 2):
        if len(text) % i == 0:
            subtext = text[:i]
            num_subtext = text.count(subtext)
            if num_subtext > 1 and num_subtext * len(subtext) == len(text):
                return True
    return False
```

Even better would be to generate only the divisors of the length of the input.
This could be done using `sympy` and the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171765/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-the-divisors-of-a-number):

```
import sympy as sym
import functools


def get_divisors(n):
    if n == 1:
        yield 1
        return
    factors = list(sym.factor_.factorint(n).items())
    nfactors = len(factors)
    f = [0] * nfactors
    while True:
        yield functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, [factors[x][0]**f[x] for x in range(nfactors)], 1)
        i = 0
        while True:
            f[i] += 1
            if f[i] <= factors[i][1]:
                break
            f[i] = 0
            i += 1
            if i >= nfactors:
                return


def has_subpattern_divs(text):
    for i in get_divisors(len(text)):
        subtext = text[:i]
        num_subtext = text.count(subtext)
        if num_subtext > 1 and num_subtext * len(subtext) == len(text):
            return True
    return False
```

A completely different approach is the one proposed in [@ВладДавидченко answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58518845/5218354):

```
def has_subpattern_find(text):
    return (text * 2).find(text, 1) != len(text)
```

or the more memory efficient (requires ~50% less additional memory compared to `has_subpattern_find2()`):

```
def has_subpattern_find2(text):
    return (text + text[:len(text) // 2 + 2]).find(text, 1) > 0
```

and it is based on the idea that if there is a exactly self-repeating string, the string itself must be found in a circularly extended string:

```
Input:      abab
Extension1: abababab
Found1:     |-abab
Extension2: ababab
Found2:     |-abab

Input:      ababa
Extension1: ababaababa
Found1:     |----ababa
Extension2: ababab
Found2:     NOT FOUND!
```

The `find`-based method are the fastest, with `has_subpattern_find()` being fastest in the small input size regime, and `has_subpattern_find2()` gets generally faster in the intermediate and large input size regime (especially in the `False` case).
For shorter inputs, the direct looping approaches (especially `has_subpattern_loop2()`) are fastest, closely followed (but sometimes surpassed by `has_subpattern_re()`), but as soon as the input gets bigger (and especially for the `False` outcome), the `has_subpattern_divs()` method gets to be the fastest (aside of `find`-based ones) by far and large, as shown by the following benchmarks.
For the `True` outcome, `has_subpattern_loop2()` gets to be the fastest due to the very small number of loops required, which is independent of the input size.

The input is generated as a function of `n` using:

```
def gen_input(n, m=0):
    g = string.ascii_lowercase
    if not m:
        m = n
    offset = '!' if n % 2 else ''
    return g[:n] * (m // min(n, len(g)) + 2) + offset
```

so that if `n` is even, the `has_subpattern*()` always return True and the opposite for odd `n`.
Note that, in general, the `has_subpattern()` function will depend not only on the raw size of the input but also on the length of the repeating string, if any. This is not explored in the benchmarks, except for the odd/even separation.

- Even Inputs

[image: bm_even_full]
[image: bm_even_zoom100]
[image: bm_even_zoom10]

- Odd Inputs

[image: bm_odd_full]
[image: bm_odd_zoom100]
[image: bm_odd_zoom10]

(Full code available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1boFqU2Qu1QqvwkbbYzQyLpFjEU0BJxB9)).

(EDITED to include some more solutions as well as comparison with regex-based solution from @RomanPerekhrest)

(EDITED to include some more solutions based on the find from @ВладДавидченко)

Answer (score 2):

Short regex approach:

```
import re

def has_subpattern_re(s):
    return bool(re.search(r'^(\w+)\1+$', s))
```

It'll provide a *close* (to initial `has_subpattern` approach) performance on small strings:

```
import timeit

...
print(timeit.timeit('has_subpattern("abababab")', 'from __main__ import has_subpattern'))
0.7413144190068124
print(timeit.timeit('has_subpattern_re("abababab")', 'from __main__ import re, has_subpattern_re'))
0.856149295999785
```

But, a significant performance increase (in about ***3-5*** times faster) on long strings:

```
print(timeit.timeit('has_subpattern("ababababababababababababababababababababababababa")', 'from __main__ import has_subpattern'))
14.669428467008402
print(timeit.timeit('has_subpattern_re("ababababababababababababababababababababababababa")', 'from __main__ import re, has_subpattern_re'))
4.308312018998549
```

And one more test for a more longer string:

```
print(timeit.timeit('has_subpattern("ababababababababababababababababababababababababaababababababababababababababababababababababababab")', 'from __main__ import has_subpattern'))
35.998031173992786
print(timeit.timeit('has_subpattern_re("ababababababababababababababababababababababababaababababababababababababababababababababababababab")', 'from __main__ import re, has_subpattern_re'))
7.010367843002314
```

Comment: With some simple modifications (essentially skipping impossible values of `i`) you should be able to get approx. on par with the `re`-based solution even with explicit looping for this input size.

Comment: For *MUCH* larger inputs, this gets to be much slower than the optimized loop approach.

Comment: @norok2, You are talking too much about your "optimized loop approach". I made comparisons to the initial OP's approach. And I did not say that there could not be another more faster approach than mine.

Comment: Nor did I implied that you said anything beyond what is in the answer. I thought it is worth noting that this is approach may or may not be faster than OP approach, and simple modifications thereof will be more performing than this. Nevertheless, this answer is a very helpful contribution to the problem.

Comment: @norok2, I think we need to accept the reality that there could be *alternatives*. "Let it be"

Answer (score 1):

Found another one solution, probably will be useful:

```
def has_subpattern(string):
    return (string * 2).find(string, 1) != len(string)
```

Comment: That will be fast, but not so memory efficient.

Comment: @norok2 for False cases where it's needed to fully go throw string?

Comment: No, the memory inefficiency is due to the need of creating a temporary array twice the size of the input when you do `s * 2` and it is independent of the final outcome. Anyway I am updating my answer with to include also this and a slightly more memory efficient version of it in the benchmarks. Also, implementing this in Cython with a modulo-ed index over `s` for the `find` operation will likely be the fastest and you will get back on business with optimal memory efficiency.