# How to filter out elements of an array that is not in a specific sequence in python

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I could not find any solution to my problem.

I am looping through many dates, and i want to get rid of the dates where they are not in a sequence:

```
days = []
new_rows = []

for row in df.iterrows():

    date = row[1][0]
    date_init_input = date.replace("-", " ")
    date_num = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_init_input, '%Y %m %d').weekday()

    counter = 0

    if len(days) == 5:
        for day in days:
            if day == counter:

                print("Correct sequence " + new_rows[counter][1][0] + " " + findDay(new_rows[counter][1][0]))
                counter += 1

                if day == 4:
                    days.clear()
                    new_rows.clear()
            else:
                print("No sequence " + new_rows[counter][1][0] + " " + findDay(new_rows[counter][1][0]))

                modDf = df.drop(new_rows[counter][0])
                days.clear()
                new_rows.clear()

    else:
        print("No sequence " + date + " " + findDay(date) + " BBBBBBBBBBB")
        days.append(date_num)
        new_rows.append(row)
```

The issue here is that the loop only moves five indexes forward, which means that any sequence between two checks get lost.

**Simplified question**

Lets say I have an array like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to remove where the numbers are not a part of a specific sequence of length 5. I want my array to look like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want further explanation please ask:)

Comment: What about `0, 1, 2`? The numbers are in sequence too. Or are you looking only for sequences of length `5`?

Comment: Do we have to increment the numbers by 1 every time? E.g. would 0,2,4,6,8 be valid?

Comment: @AndrejKesely it has to be a specific length of 5

Comment: @twerk_it_606 It increases with one each time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String subpattern recognition optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507418/string-subpattern-recognition-optimization)

Comment: @norok2 That question only returns true if there is a pattern, i know that there is a pattern here, but i want to filter them out.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm? Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up using, i feel this is an unefficient approach, but it works:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
pattern = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

end = 5
start = 0

for i in array:
    new_array = array[start:end]
    if new_array == pattern:
        print(str(new_array) + " Correct")
    else:
        print(str(new_array) + " False")

    end += 1
    start += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach. You can use a temporary list to keep track of a pattern match. While looping through the dates, append days to the temporary list as long as they are compliant with the sequence. As soon as they diverge from the sequence, simply empty the temporary list to zero. If they complete the sequence, add the list onto your resulting list (new_rows in your case).

So, in pseudocode:

```
result = []
pattern = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
temp_list = []

for day in alldays:
    if day == pattern[len(temp_list)]
        temp_list.append(day)
    if len(temp_list) == len(pattern)
        result = result + temp_list
        temp_list = []
```

Comment: What is len.append(day)?

Comment: An errror, I fixed it. That line and the line above are responsible for adding the day to the temporary list as long as it fits with the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward method based on your simplified version but relies on strings, join everything to a string and search for exact matches of what you need:

```
import re

seq = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
seq_s = ','.join([str(i) for i in seq])

search = '0,1,2,3,4'
```

Use `re.finditer` to return non-overlapping matches, and split the results, for added efficiency we can keep the `found_sequence` as a generator untill we decide what needs to be done:

```
found_seq = (m[0].split(',') for m in re.finditer(search, seq_s))

for i in found_seq:
    print(i)

Output:
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

To return it into a list:

```
found_list = []

for i in found_seq:
    #do something like...
    i = [int(n) for n in i]
    found_list.extend(i)

found_list

Output:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

(EDITED): Here are a couple of ways of achieving this:

```
def remove_non_standard_buffer(items, template):
    buffer = []
    len_template = len(template)
    j = 0
    for item in items:
        if item == template[j] and j < len_template:
            buffer.append(item)
            j += 1
        elif item == template[0]:
            buffer = [item]
            j = 1
        else:
            buffer = []
            j = 0
        if len(buffer) == len_template:
            for buffer_item in buffer:
                yield buffer_item
            buffer = []
            j = 0


def remove_non_standard_slicing(items, template):
    start = 0
    end = len(template)
    for item in items:
        test_seq = items[start:end]
        if test_seq == template:
            yield from template
        end += 1
        start += 1


def remove_non_standard_for(items, template):
    len_template = len(template)
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        if items[i:i + len_template] == template:
            yield from template


def remove_non_standard_while(items, template):
    len_template = len(template)
    len_items = len(items)
    i = 0
    while i < len_items - len_template + 1:
        if items[i:i + len_template] == template:
            yield from template
            i += len_template
        else:
            i += 1


def remove_non_standard_while_reverse(items, template):
    i = 0
    len_template = len(template)
    len_items = len(items)
    while i < len_items - len_template + 1:
        to_yield = True
        for j in range(len_template - 1, -1, -1):
            if items[i + j] != template[j]:
                to_yield = False
                break
        if to_yield:
            yield from template
            i += len_template
        else:
            i += j + 1

def remove_non_standard_count(items, template):
    n = 0
    i = 0
    len_template = len(template)
    len_items = len(items)
    while i < len_items - len_template + 1:
        if items[i:i + len_template] == template:
            n += 1
            i += len_template
        else:
            i += 1
    return template * n


def remove_non_standard_count_reverse(items, template):
    n = 0
    i = 0
    len_template = len(template)
    len_items = len(items)
    while i < len_items - len_template + 1:
        to_yield = True
        for j in range(len_template - 1, -1, -1):
            if items[i + j] != template[j]:
                to_yield = False
                break
        if to_yield:
            n += 1
            i += len_template
        else:
            i += j + 1
    return template * n
```

and testing it:

```
ll = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(remove_non_standard_buffer(ll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(remove_non_standard_reverse(ll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(remove_non_standard_slicing(ll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(remove_non_standard_for(ll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(remove_non_standard_while(ll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(remove_non_standard_while_reverse(ll, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

with the respective timings:

```
%timeit list(remove_non_standard_buffer(ll * 1000, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.35 ms per loop
%timeit list(remove_non_standard_slicing(ll * 1000, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.35 ms per loop
%timeit list(remove_non_standard_for(ll * 1000, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 3.19 ms per loop
%timeit list(remove_non_standard_while(ll * 1000, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.29 ms per loop
%timeit list(remove_non_standard_while_reverse(ll * 1000, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop
%timeit remove_non_standard_count(ll * 1000, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.85 ms per loop
%timeit remove_non_standard_count_reverse(ll * 1000, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop
```

`remove_non_standard_slicing()` uses substantially the same approach as [@EliasKnudsen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59910862/5218354), but the approach with the `remove_non_standard_while()` is considerably faster.
`remove_non_standard_while_reverse()` is even more efficient, but pays the relatively inefficient looping in Python.

Instead, the `_count` solutions are a somewhat over-optimized for `list` version of `while` that take advantage of the faster `list` multiplication operations (and therefore it is probably less useful for `pandas` dataframes).

Comment: @EliasKnudsen perhaps you may want to look into some of these approaches, which may be faster for your problem.