# Splitting a 1D numpy array to identical array sets and return number of sets

Tags: python, numpy

The array is 'num_array':

```
[1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1
 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 2
 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 3
 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 3 1
 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1]
```

I've tried to use a for loop:

```
a = num_array [:3]
b = num_array.reshape(int(len(num_array)/len(a)), int(len(a)))
print(num_array)
for a in np.nditer(num_array):
        print (b)
```

But it doesn't come out right because it's not identical as it only checks the first 3 indices (a).
I'm a python beginner of 2 months

Comment: What output do you want to get?

Comment: I got: ` [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [3 2 1]
 [3 2 1]
 [3 2 1]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [3 2 1]
 [3 2 1]
 [3 2 1]] ` *not all characters

Comment: But i want to get identical rows i.e: r0 = r1 = r2 ... = rn

Comment: using a function that takes `[num_array]` argument

Comment: Your problem is not specified exactly enough yet, I think. What do you mean by "I want to get identical rows"? Does the input always have the structure of repeated sub-arrays? Or are you looking for an algorithm that finds out whether there are such repetitions?

Comment: I'm trying to define a function that takes in an array that has a randomly repeated number pattern (eg: `[2 3 5 6 2 3 5 7 5 6 2 3 5 6 2 3 5 7 5 6]`). I want to loop through the array and group each pattern: '2356235756' for example into separate rows and increment iterator by 1 each loop. In this example, it would return 2 but should also work for any set of number pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code tries all the divisors of the array length and then checks whether all sub-arrays are equal. Providing `-1` as parameter in `reshape(-1, k)` automatically calculates the correct dimension. (Note that the loop to get the divisors is quite simplistic, it could be sped up e.g. as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171765/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-all-the-divisors-of-a-number).)

```py
import numpy as np

def find_repeat_length(num_array):
    n = num_array.size
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % k == 0:  # if k is a divisor of n
            arr = num_array.reshape(-1, k)
            if (arr == arr[0]).all(): # check wether all rows are equal to each other
                return k
num_array_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1])
num_array_2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5])

for num_array in (num_array_1, num_array_2):
    rep_len = find_repeat_length(num_array)
    print(f'repeat length is {rep_len}: {num_array[:rep_len]} repeated {len(num_array) // rep_len} times')
```

Result:

```
repeat length is 18: [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 3 2 1] repeated 9 times
repeat length is 8: [1 2 3 3 2 1 1 5] repeated 3 times
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however, running the function provided on `num_array2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5])` it gives `repeat length is 8: [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2]` where I expect: `[1 2 3 3 2 1 1 5]`

Comment: Maybe something went wrong with copy-pasting? I just changed my code to your new example and the result seems to be OK.

Comment: Yes! I didn't copy the last ` // rep_len} times') ` of your code. Thanks, it works