# displaying the factors of a number

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to get all the factors of a number provided by a user and after a button click displaying all the factors on a MessageBox.

This is what <strike>my code</strike> code taken from [Getting Factors of a Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549482/getting-factors-of-a-number) answer by [Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61974/mark-byers) looks like, I thought I was pretty close, but I'm displaying the number of factors not the actual factor numbers.

For example if the user types in 10 and uses a button click, the MessageBox displays the number 4, but i'm wanting it to display the actual factors of 10 which should be 1,2,5,10.

***how can I display the factors?**

```
public int Divisors(int fact)
    {
        int number = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int factorCount = 0;
        int sqrt = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number));

        for (int i = 1; i < sqrt; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                factorCount += 2; //  We found a pair of factors.
            }
        }

        // Check if our number is an exact square.
        if (sqrt * sqrt == number)
        {
            factorCount++;
        }

        return factorCount;
    }

private void ShowallButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int input = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        double output = Divisors(input);

        MessageBox.Show(+output + "");
    }
```

Comment: Instead of updating factor count, why don't you store the factor in an array and then display that array (by maybe converting to string).

Comment: You also need to correct the for loop to `for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)`

Comment: well.... i'm still new at C# and I haven't really figured out how to use arrays....

Comment: You can start figuring that out by solving this issue... if not array you can use string to generate the output and return it from the method.

Comment: I seriously doubt that it is "your code" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549482/getting-factors-of-a-number. SO requires attribution when copy/pasting code - attribution edited in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public List<int> Divisors(int fact)
    {
        List<int> factors = new List<int>();
        int number = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int factorCount = 0;
        int sqrt = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number));

        for (int i = 1; i < sqrt; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                factors.Add(i);
                factorCount += 2; //  We found a pair of factors.
            }
        }

        // Check if our number is an exact square.
        if (sqrt * sqrt == number)
        {
            factorCount++;
        }

        // return factorCount;
        return factors;
    }
    private void ShowallButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int input = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        List<int> factors = Divisors(input);
        string message = $"The Divisors are {string.Join(",", factors)}";
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
```

Comment: I am not going to update any of your logic, but this is how i would go about displaying the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very close at all.

Lets look at the factorisation first

[% Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator)

> The remainder operator % computes the remainder after dividing its
>   first operand by its second operand.

```
public static void Divisors(int number )
{
   for (var x = 1; x <= number; x++)
      if (number % x == 0) // no remainder it must be a factor
         Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

**usage**

```
Divisors(10);
```

**Output**

```
1
2
5
10
```

---

Now Lets return an `Enumerable` using `yield`

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Divisors(int number )
{
   for (var x = 1; x <= number; x++)
      if (number % x == 0) // no remainder it must be a factor
         yield return x;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var results = Divisors(10);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

**Output**

```
1, 2, 5, 10
```

---

**Additional resources**

[yield (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

> When you use the yield contextual keyword in a statement, you indicate
>   that the method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an
>   iterator. Using yield to define an iterator removes the need for an
>   explicit extra class (the class that holds the state for an
>   enumeration, see IEnumerator for an example) when you implement the
>   IEnumerable and IEnumerator pattern for a custom collection type.

[String.Join Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a
>   collection, using the specified separator between each element or
>   member.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ShowallButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var input = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        var output = Divisors(input);

        var message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output);
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    public List<int> Divisors(int number)
    {
        var factors = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                factors.Add(i);
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }
```