# Sum of proper divisor upto N

Tags: number-theory

I have to find sum of proper divisor upto N (N <= 20000000). I have pre-calculate this function with complexity O(N * log(N)) which takes upto 4 second. How can I optimize it or any alternate solution will be greatly accepted.

Example: N = 10 answer is 86, N = 1000 answer is 823080

```
int f(){
   for(LL i = 1; i <= m; i++){
       for(LL j = i; j <= m; j += i){
           ans[j] += i;
       }
   }
   for(LL i = 2; i <= m; i++)     ans[i] += ans[i - 1];
}
```

I also tried using prime factorization and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Properties) formula, but it takes more time than above algorithm.

Comment: This question has already been answered very well at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323572/how-to-find-total-number-of-divisors-upto-n/8337647#8337647

Answer (score 0):

I can't edit my previous comment, only to say that the problem referenced by my comment is a little bit different, but with a minor adjustment it answers also this question.
Just multiply inside the loop by the divisor itself.