# How can I make this code faster?

Tags: python

I have written this code for solving Euler Project No 12, but my code runs slow.

How can I make it running faster? I have read some suggests about finding divisors, but I do not understand the logic of using `sqrt` for `n`.

Can you explain the logic of it?

Here's my code:

```
def sumdiv(n):
  l=[d for d in range(1,int(n/2)+1) if n%d==0] # used n/2 to short loop
  return len(l)+1 # added n itself
trnums=[1,3]

while sumdiv(trnums[-1])<=501:
  k=trnums[-1]-trnums[-2]+1
  trnums.append(trnums[-1]+k)
print(trnums[-2:])
```

Comment: use `[d for d in range(1,int(math.sqrt(n))+1) if n%d==0]`, you're not finding any divisors after this point. That _will_ make your code faster.

Comment: I've already know this method but I need logic of using sqrt

Comment: Is your question "why should I stop at `int(math.sqrt(n))+1`?

Comment: Yes , Why I should stop at sqrt?

Comment: If `xy = n`, then `x <= sqrt(n) <= y`, and if you identify a pair `(x, y)`, you don't need to find `(y, x)` separately.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre you mean divisors instead of primer numbers, don't you?

Comment: yeah, right. But in that case multiply by 2 unless you get a perfect square.

Comment: Yes . I know prime divisors . I need all divisor

Comment: you don't need divisors, you need the number of divisors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110344/algorithm-to-calculate-the-number-of-divisors-of-a-given-number someone dupehammer already used my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are divisors of `n` if `a * b = n`. You can, without loss of generality, set `b >= a`. Therefore `a * a` is the upper limit; i.e. you only need to consider up to and including the square root of `n`. Once you have an `a`, you can trivially infer `b`.

You can set the upper limit to be `d * d <= n` rather than `d <= sqrt(n)` so obviating *any* computation of a square root. That will be marginally faster still.

Comment: lest take for example 28.

Comment: the divisors of 28 are 1,2,4,7,14,28. I have changed my code. but asnwer is wrong

Comment: n=28
for i in range(1,int(n**0.5)+1):
  if n%i==0:
    print(i)

Comment: answers are 1,2,4

Comment: Yes, they are the `a` in the set. You need to compute `n / a` to add in the other pair. Then you're done!

Comment: Just make sure you don't add the final element twice for the case where `n` is a prime number squared. E.g. 49.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to know the number of divisors:

For any number `N` there are always an even number of divisors as every dividor `x` requires to be multiplied by another `y` that is itself a divisor of `N` except if `x=sqrt(N)` yileds an integer result as that would mean that `x*x=N` and that would be an only number. So every divisor is grouped in pairs except for `sqrt(N)` if it results to be a divisor.

Then you first check if the root is a divisor and then just calculate until it and add two to the count each time as the rest will always be pairs:

```
def number_of_divisors(n):
    root = math.sqrt(n)
    if root == int(root):
        number = 1
        limit = int(root)
    else:
        number = 0
        limit = int(root) + 1
    for i in range(1, limit):
        if (n % i) == 0:
            number += 2
    return number

i = 1
s = 1
while number_of_divisors(s) < 501:
    i += 1
    s += i

print(i) # 12375
print(s) # 76576500
print(number_of_divisors(s)) # 576
```