# Optimize and speed up the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, triangular

I wrote a program about triangular numbers, which are derived from the sum of natural numbers one after the other. For example, the third triangular number is equal to: 1 + 2 + 3 = 6.
NOW I WANT to find Divisors of triangular numbers. for example the third triangular number have 4 divisors which equal to : 1,2,3,6
so I want to find the first number which have more than 500 divisors .
program working fine but slow so I don't get an answer .
what's your opinion for optimize my program?
some triangular number Whith their divisors:
(**1**: 1) ,
(**3**: 1,3) ,
(**6**: 1,2,3,6) ,
(**10**: 1,2,5,10) ,
(**15**: 1,3,5,15) ,
(**21**: 1,3,7,21) ,
(**28**: 1,2,4,7,14,28)

```
def triangular(n):
    a= []
    for i in range (2,n):
        if n % i == 0 :
            a.append(i)
    if len(a) > 498:
        return True
    else :
        a.clear()
        return False
x=1
n=x
while x>0:
    if triangular(n):
        print(n)
        break
    else:
        n+=x+1
        x+=1
```

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for improvements, you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0):

Now, I adapted some code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118712/14316282) which works very fast to find how many divisors a number has, so this should work much much quicker than your current solution:

```
import operator
import functools


def PrimesPlus():
    """Superset of primes"""

    yield 2
    yield 3
    i = 5
    while True:
        yield i
        if i % 6 == 1:
            i += 2
        i += 2


def GetPrimeDecomp(n):
    """Returns a dict d with n = product p ^ d[p]"""

    d = {}
    primes = PrimesPlus()
    for p in primes:
        while n % p == 0:
            n /= p
            d[p] = d.setdefault(p, 0) + 1
        if n == 1:
            return d


def NumberOfDivisors(n):
    """Returns how many divisors a number has"""
    d = GetPrimeDecomp(n)
    powers_plus = map(lambda x: x + 1, d.values())
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, powers_plus, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 1
    n = 1
    while x > 0:
        if NumberOfDivisors(n) > 500:
            print(n)
            break
        else:
            x += 1
            n += x
```